# Building JAR from Android SDK

Tags: java, android, jar

I have a task to create a android specific .jar file (in java) so that that it can be used in different projects for developing android apps. I am planning to develop the whole .jar file in Android SDK .
But I have a strange situation where I need .property/.xml file to store database passwords. So my question is

1. Can i have a .property/.xml file as a part of .jar where i can read/write value.(i guess it is not possible).
2. If not than should i create temp. files while my jar is invoked. In this case i need to change the password when ever the app (using my jar ) starts.

I am really confused where to go from here.

Hope my question is understandable.

Comment: Sorry, but question is unclear ... first you should use well know terms ( *android specific .jar file (in java)* did you mean android library?) ... next: saving to android resources is not possible ... next: saving from android library is possible in the same way as from not  library (search for: android's storage options) ... Question is: where is the question? ... answer to 2nd point is up to you ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create an aar file you have to add the following declaration into your build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
```

Then when you'll build the project you will see the aar file into the following directory:

```
build/outputs/aar/
```

If you rename the aar file to zip and unzip it, you'll see the classes.jar file.

However you have to understand what is an aar file. So according to the 
Android Tools Project Site:

The 'aar' bundle is the binary distribution of an Android Library Project.

The file extension is .aar, and the maven artifact type should be aar as well, but the file itself a simple zip file with the following entries:

```
 /AndroidManifest.xml (mandatory)
 /classes.jar (mandatory)
 /res/ (mandatory)
 /R.txt (mandatory)
 /assets/ (optional)
 /libs/*.jar (optional)
 /jni/<abi>/*.so (optional)
 /proguard.txt (optional)
 /lint.jar (optional)
```

These entries are directly at the root of the zip file.

Comment: But what about if i want to add a property file in .jar. can i edit that file as well. Or do we have an other option.??

Comment: @SidharthDash No you can't edit it yourself. You can create a libs folder in the project structure and you can add other jar files. Or you can refer other aar projects through gradle.